# JSF Application creating too many DB connections

Tags: mysql, jsf-2, connection-pooling

I've built a (relatively)simple JSF application using a MYSQL 5.1 db and Tomcat 7. Things are working in the sense that nothing blows up, but there is a curiosity...

Using the MySQL workbench, I can see that, over a period of time, I build up an ever increasing list of DB connections that are never released. Each one has the format:

```
[id] [user] [host] [dbname] [command] [time] [State] [info]
```

**State** is always blank and **Command** is always 'sleep'.

I'm following best practices when opening and closing connections, statements, and as far as I can tell, none of my ManagedBeans has any persistent connection to the dataSource, all of them should fall out of scope anyway as soon as I switch between pages.

I'm struggling to find answers, and that's partly because I'm not quite sure where to look. Any suggestions on what to review/troubleshoot, are there some common JSF/DBCP pitfalls I'm not aware of ?

This might be useful:

```
<Resource 
    name="jdbc/TrackerDB" 
    auth="Container" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="20" 
    maxIdle="10" 
    maxWait="100"
    username="xxxx" 
    password="xxxx" 
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
    logAbandoned="true"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tracker"
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of persistence framework are you using?

If it's JPA you should `close()` the EntityManager each time (falling out of scope isn't good enough)!

If it's hibernate you should `close()` the Session each time.

If it's JDBC you should `close()` the Statement each time.

Closing such a resource is usually done in a `finally` clause (of the `try` block).

P.S. You don't mention closing ResultSets. I assume you close those too?

Comment: Doing that already, its JDBC and everything opened is properly closed.

Comment: @JHarnach what's your maxIdle config of DBCP? Default is 8.

Comment: Edited original post, and yes resultsets get closed too.

Comment: @JHarnach have you tried running the application with maxIdle=1 to see whether the connections are actually permitted to be waiting by DBCP or not? Because by default unused connections are not closed but re-used at some time (maxWait is for when all connections are in use - how long to wait to get a connection) see http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html (as if you hadn't already):)

Comment: Setting maxIdle=1 does indeed cause my application to furiously reuse connections. Interesting... this requires a larger test. Hmm.

Comment: The problem is with my implementation. maxIdle=1 causes my application to reuse one connection, but it will never create more than that. Boo answers that raise more questions :)

Comment: Bah, I was creating new connection POOLS instead of new connections. Thanks for the help!